# How to calculate PDF when Sampling Lights Directly

Tags: graphics, sampling, montecarlo, raytracing

I am reading "Ray tracing the rest of your life". I am confused when I come to Chapter 7 Sampling Lights Directly.

[Page of Chapter 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qigs8.png)

I am not sure what 'p_q(q)' means, and why the probability of sampling dw and dA must be the same.

What is the correct method to calculate pdf when Sampling Lights?

Comment: dw and dA are just different representations of the same sample. Therefore, they have the same distribution as the sample itself. The meaning of `p_q(q)` should be explained somewhere else in the book. Might be the probability of sampling a given direction `q`.

Answer (score 0):

looks like `p_q(q)` is the probability of picking point `q` arbitrarily on the light source surface. So `p_q(q)` is equal to `1/A` and `A` is the area of light source surface.

`dw` and `dA` are the same representation of a certain direction, `dA` can be considered as the projection of `dw` on the sphere with radius `distance(p,q)`.